# How to stack 2d array on an existing 3d array (python)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to "stack" array a2 below a1 such that I get array b with the following shape

```
a1.shape => (2, 50, 241)
a2.shape => (50, 241)

# goal
b.shape => (3, 50, 241)
```

This was my attempt, but np.stack requires the same shape

```
b = np.stack([a1, a2])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
arr1 = np.random.rand(2, 50, 241)
arr2 = np.random.rand(50, 241)
```

Reshape arr2 so it's got the same 3d structure:

```
arr2 = arr2.reshape(1, 50, 241)
```

Vstack it:

```
arr3 = np.vstack((arr1, arr2))

>>> arr3.shape
(3, 50, 241)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your arrays are numpy arrays, try [np.append](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html)

```
b = np.append(a1, [a2])
```

This is assuming you are trying to construct b such that a2 is the last item of b and a1 is the first 2 items.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
a2_reshaped = a2.reshape((1,) + a2.shape)
b = np.stack([a1, a2_reshaped])
```